# Посоветуйте MVC-фреймворк для JavaScript

Tags: javascript, history-api, observer, mvc

Чтобы имел поддержку History API и не сильно много весил.

Только, желательно, не первую ссылку из Google, а то с чем реально приходилось работать. Какие плюсы, минусы, возможные грабли.

Comment: Лично я не понимаю что значит MVC javascript фреймворк...<br>
Насколько я знаю - ни один js фреймворк не ограничивается строгими рамками MVC, следовательно фреймворк можно юзать любой, а сделать MVC вам поможет мозг ( должен вернее :) )

Comment: @AlexWindHope, цель вопроса - наладить согласованную работу front-end разработчиков над проектом. У готовое решения обычно есть  документация, комьюнити, подержка. А если ничего подходящего не найдется, тогда уже мозг, нада же и его когда-нибудь использовать... :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Backbone.js**](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) на мой взгляд лучший js MVC фреймворк.

ссылки:

- [Написание сложных интерфейсов с Backbone.js](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/118782/)
- [Backbone.js для «чайников»](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/127049/)
- [Hello Backbone.js](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/) - 5 прекрасный уроков

> Самое главное — после прочтения сделайте правильные выводы:
>
> 1. Если Вам нужен только селект с кнопками плюс минус — прочь от MVC, пишите в лоб — можно с помощью «Jquery/Dojo/MooTools/Моя*любимая*аякс_библиотека».
> 2. Если Вам нужно 20 таких селектов с кнопками — пишите плагин для «Jquery/Dojo/MooTools/Моя*любимая*аякс_библиотека» и используйте в свое удовольствие.
> 3. Если Вам нужно написать интерфейс к «Gmail/Google docs/Facebook/еще какая то крутая жесть» — смотрите в сторону MVC, Observer и т.д.

©[zoommy](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/119369/#comment_3918357)

Comment: Можно в двух словах о своем опыте использования Backbone? И, исправьте, пожалуйста, ссылку. Она ссылается на этот тред.

Comment: опытом только обзавожусь - недавно начал использовать, но меня удовлетворяет кол-во информации по данному фреймворку, а главное радует наличие [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) - некоторая альтернатива LINQ`у, который очень удобно использовать

Comment: Отлично, спасибо! А, перед тем как остановились на Backbone.js, другие библиотеки подобного типа рассматривали?

Comment: да, была одна, к сожалению не помню как называлась, но суть сводилась к функции, которая имела примерно такой вид ``$(описываем модель, описываем вьюху, описываем контроллер)``

Comment: QOOXDOO тебе в помощь :))